# How to plot real time graphs using GNUPLOT in C?

Tags: c, time, graph, gnuplot

I am able to plot simple graphs of sinx cosx graph using `gnuplot`. But I am not able to update it in real time. By real time, I mean to say that its x-axis should change automatically. How can I do that.?

Here is the code for simple sinx plotting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     FILE *fp;
     fp = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
     fprintf(fp, " plot[-5:5] sin(x)\n");
     pclose(fp);
     return 0;
}
```

This code plots a graph of `sinx` with `x-axis` range of -5 to 5, but how will I set the range in case of real time. How to plot a real time graph, please help, thanks.!

Comment: Why do you want to do this from c, do you rather want to use a library instead of calling gnuplot?

Comment: @martin because the complete project is in c and I have to integrate it. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Does it need to be gnuplot, can't you use a diffrent graph library?

Comment: @martin yes i can use different graph library, if you know please suggest me, but it should be through c language.

Comment: In the linked duplicate, they also mention the solution with popen and that you should use the replot command after changing your axis. If that solves your problem, makr it as a duplicate, if not, edit your question to show the difference.